# How to watch loading state in vue-apollo when the fetchPolicy is no-cache?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, graphql, vue-apollo

If the `fetchPolicy` is set to `no-cache` I cannot watch the loading state. I tried different approaches.

The most common usage for me is the `apollo` component property:

```
  apollo: {
    trips: {
      query: gql`...`,

      loadingKey: 'loading',

      watchLoading (isLoading, countModifier) {
        console.log('isLoading', isLoading)
        console.log('countModifier', countModifier)
      }
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      trips: [],
      loading: 0
    }
  },
```

So

1. watchLoading callback doesn't get called regardless if I specified loadingKey or not
2. loading property never changed

I also tried to use computed property:

```
showLoader () {
    return this.$apollo.queries.trips.loading
}
```

That always return false.

And all of above is right only when `no-cache` is set.

Answer (score 0):

There is property on the query called `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange` ([docs](https://apollo.vuejs.org/api/apollo-query.html#props)).

Either use it on a single query:

```
apollo: {
  trips: {
    query: gql`...`,
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
  }
}
```

Or set it as default on the client:

```
const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
  defaultOptions: {
    $query: {
      notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
});
```